# Función dados en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Necesito crear una función que simule tirar `n` dados aleatoriamente e imprima una tabla donde una columna sean los números, osea del 1 al 6, y en la otra cuantas veces salio cada número.

Este es mi código:

```
import random 


def dados(n):  
    A = [random.randint(1,6) for x in range(n)]  
    print('{0:^8s} {1:^8s}'.format('Numero','Veces'))  
    s=0  
    for i in A:  
        for x in range(1,7):  
            if i==x:  
                s=s+1  
            print('{0:1d} {1:10d}'.format(x,s))
```

Comment: Muéstranos el código que has intentado realizar para poder darte una respuesta mas concreta o ayudarte con los errores que tengas.

Comment: Puedes hacer la edición de tu pregunta e incluir el código y puedes darle estilo de código seleccionándolo todo y presionando las teclas `ctrl + k`.

Comment: Hola Lucía , bienvenida a [es.so], para añadir información o código a la pregunta usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/173040/edit) que hay debajo de ella, recuerda formatear el código adecuadamente, para ello solo tienes que seleccionarlo y pulsar `Ctrl` + `k` o  el botón `{}` del editor, con ello además de resaltado de sintaxis se conservará el formato y algo tan importante en Python como es la identación. Un saludo.

Comment: ahi lo mejore en la pregunta, mas o menos

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tus `for` anidados en los que intentas contar las veces que aparece cada número están en el orden incorrecto. En todo caso debes iterar sobre los números del 1 al 6 y por cada uno contar las veces que aparece en la lista:

```
import random 


def dados(n):  
    A = [random.randint(1,6) for x in range(n)]  
    print('{0:^8s} {1:^8s}'.format('Numero','Veces'))  
    s=0  
    for i in A:  
        for x in range(1,7):  
            if i==x:  
                s=s+1  
            print('{0:1d} {1:10d}'.format(x,s))
```

También puedes usar `list.count` en vez del segundo `for`:

```
import random 


def dados(n):  
    a = [random.randint(1, 6) for x in range(n)]  
    print('{0:^8s} {1:^8s}'.format('Numero', 'Veces'))  

    for x in range(1, 7):
        s = a.count(x) 
        print('{0:>7} {1:>7}'.format(x, s))
```

Existen muchas formas de hacer esto, por ejemplo usando un diccionario con los números del 1 al 6 como claves y como valores el número de veces que aparece:

```
import random 


def dados(n):
    veces = {k: 0 for k in range(1, 7)}
    for _ in range(n):
        veces[random.randint(1, 6)] += 1

    print('{0:^8s} {1:^8s}'.format('Numero','Veces'))   
    for n, veces in veces.items():  
        print('{0:>7} {1:>7}'.format(n, veces))
```

O usar `collections.Counter`:

```
import random 
import collections

def dados(n):
    veces = collections.Counter((random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n))) 

    print('{0:^8s} {1:^8s}'.format('Numero','Veces'))   
    for n, veces in veces.items():  
        print('{0:>7} {1:>7}'.format(n, veces))
```

Ejemplos:

> ```
> >>> dados(10)
>  Numero   Veces  
>       1       1
>       2       1
>       3       2
>       4       0
>       5       2
>       6       4
>
> >>> dados(10000)
>  Numero   Veces  
>       1    1719
>       2    1658
>       3    1627
>       4    1692
>       5    1689
>       6    1615
> ```